# UINavigationController pushViewController not working

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a double-tap gesture on a view controller `iRpImageViewerViewController` (topmost on the navigation stack), and each time a view on `iRpImageViewerViewController` is double-tapped, it pushes a image editor view controller `iRpImageEditorViewController` onto the stack, that's why there are several of them, none of which appeared. Each time I double-tap, it's added, but never appears. self is simply the class that houses this double-tap gesture `iRpImageViewerViewController`, and does in fact have a navigationController per the LLDB output

`po self.navigationController` returns a navigation controller as expected.

`po self.navigationController viewControllers` shows a new view controller being added to the list with each `pushViewController` statement encountered, yet the pushed item won't show up on screen.

I shouldn't have to push and then move to front, right??  Doesn't the push automatically make it the frontmost view controller?

Note that my navigation controller is NOT the root controller in my hierarchy, starting from the window.  I have a full screen map view controller, then a half-screen 'dashboard' view controller, then within that I have a window on the dashboard that has a picture, and that picture is itself a view controller.  So starting with the picture view controller, shown here, you can walk through everything that happens

```
@implementation iRpDashboardHeaderImagesViewController
{
    IGGridView *theGridViewControl;
    UIView *theGridParentView;
    iRpImageSet *thePropertyImageSet;
    iRpDashboardViewController *dashboardViewController;
    UIImageView *primaryImageMarker;
    UINavigationController *imageEditorNavController;
    iRpImageViewerViewController *imageViewerVC;
}


    -(id)initWithParentViewController:(iRpDashboardViewController*)parentController
    {
        self = [super init];
        if (self)
        {
            dashboardViewController = parentController;
        }
        return self;
    }


    -(void)loadView
    {
        // Just a basic size to get started... the final size is set later in another method.  I believe actual height will be 220
        CGRect theGridRectangle = CGRectMake(0, 0, 375, 220);
        theGridViewControl = [[IGGridView alloc]initWithFrame:theGridRectangle style:IGGridViewStyleSingleCellPaging];

        // Set additional properties to configure the grid view
        theGridViewControl.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        theGridViewControl.selectionType = IGGridViewSelectionTypeCell;
        theGridViewControl.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        theGridViewControl.allowHorizontalBounce = NO;
        theGridViewControl.alwaysBounceVertical = NO;

        self.view = theGridViewControl;
    }


    -(void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        imageEditorNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];        
    }




    -(void)presentImageViewerForCellAtPath:(IGCellPath*)path
    {
        iRpImageAndMedia *imageAndMediaItem = [thePropertyImageSet objectAtIndex:path.columnIndex];

        imageViewerVC = [[iRpImageViewerViewController alloc] initWithParentViewController:self imageSet:thePropertyImageSet initialImageAndMedia:imageAndMediaItem];
        imageViewerVC.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
        imageViewerVC.navigationItem.title =  dashboardViewController.parcelNbr;
        imageViewerVC.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(imageEditorDone)];

        // Create a navigation controller to embed the image viewer view controller inside. 
        [imageEditorNavController pushViewController:imageViewerVC animated:YES];

        [self presentViewController:imageEditorNavController animated:YES completion:^(void)
            {
            }];

    }

    -(void)imageEditorDone
    {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];
    }

}
```

...

```
@implementation iRpImageViewerViewController
{
    IGGridView *theMainImageGridviewControl;
    iRpImageSet *thePropertyImageSet;
    iRpImageFilmstripViewController *theFilmstripViewController;
    iRpImageAndMedia *initialMediaItem;
    UIImageView *primaryImageMarker;
    iRpImageEditorViewController *imageEditorVC;
    UIViewController *theParentViewController;

}


    -(id)initWithParentViewController:(UIViewController*)parentViewController imageSet:(iRpImageSet*)imageSet initialImageAndMedia:(iRpImageAndMedia*)imageAndMedia
        {
            self = [super initWithNibName:@"iRpImageViewerViewController" bundle:nil];
            if (self)
            {
                theParentViewController = parentViewController;
                theFilmstripViewController = [[iRpImageFilmstripViewController alloc] initWithParentViewController:self imageSet:imageSet initialImageAndMedia:imageAndMedia];
                initialMediaItem = imageAndMedia;
                thePropertyImageSet = imageSet;
            }
            return self;
        }


    -(void)viewDidLoad
        {
            [super viewDidLoad];

            theMainImageGridviewControl = [[IGGridView alloc]initWithFrame:self.mainImagePlaceholderView.frame style:IGGridViewStyleSingleCellPaging];            
            // Set additional properties to configure the grid view
            theMainImageGridviewControl.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
            theMainImageGridviewControl.selectionType = IGGridViewSelectionTypeCell;
            theMainImageGridviewControl.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
            theMainImageGridviewControl.allowHorizontalBounce = NO;
            theMainImageGridviewControl.alwaysBounceHorizontal = NO;
            theMainImageGridviewControl.alwaysBounceVertical = NO;

            [self.mainImagePlaceholderView addSubview:theMainImageGridviewControl];

            [self addAChildViewController:theFilmstripViewController toViewWithTag:self.filmstripPlaceholderView.tag];
        }


    -(void)addGestureRecognizersToCell:(IGGridViewImageCell*)cell
        {
            static NSMutableArray *recognizers;
            UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapRecognizer;
            UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressRecognizer;

            if (!recognizers)
            {
                recognizers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

                doubleTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTapRecognizer:)];
                doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;

                longPressRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPressRecognizer:)];

                [recognizers addObject:doubleTapRecognizer];
                [recognizers addObject:longPressRecognizer];
            }

            // Don't do anything because already processed.
            [cell removeGestureRecognizer:doubleTapRecognizer];
            [cell removeGestureRecognizer:longPressRecognizer];
            [cell registerGestures:recognizers];

        }



    -(void)handleDoubleTapRecognizer:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
        {
            NSLog(@"Double Tapped on ImageViewerViewController's main image, so opening editor");

            IGCellPath *pathForCurrentCell = [self pathForCurrentCell];
            iRpImageAndMedia *imageAndMediaItem = [thePropertyImageSet objectAtIndex:pathForCurrentCell.columnIndex];

            imageEditorVC = [[iRpImageEditorViewController alloc] initWithImageAndMediaItem:imageAndMediaItem];
            imageEditorVC.navigationItem.title = @"Photo Details Editor";
            imageEditorVC.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(imageEditorDone)];
            imageEditorVC.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;


            [self.navigationController pushViewController:imageEditorVC animated:YES];
        }


    -(void)imageEditorDone
        {
            [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }


    -(void)imageEditorCancelled
        {
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        }
}
```

...
This class below is the one that keeps being added to the navigation controller, but never appears.
...

```
@implementation iRpImageEditorViewController 
{
    __weak IBOutlet UISwitch *primarySwitch;
    __weak IBOutlet UISwitch *postToWebSwitch;
    __weak IBOutlet UITextView *descriptionView;
    __weak IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
    __weak IBOutlet UITextField *mediaDate;
    __weak IBOutlet UITextField *orderNbr;
    __weak IBOutlet UITextField *updatedBy;
    __weak IBOutlet UITextField *updateDate;

    iRpImageAndMedia *theImageAndMediaItem;
}



    -(id)initWithImageAndMediaItem:(iRpImageAndMedia*)imageAndMediaItem
    {
        if (self = [super initWithNibName:@"iRpImageEditorViewController" bundle:nil])
        {
            theImageAndMediaItem = imageAndMediaItem;
        }
        return self;
    }



    -(void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

        [self populateUserInterface];
    }



    -(void)populateUserInterface
    {
        imageView.image = [theImageAndMediaItem pictureForViewOfSize:imageView.bounds.size];

        primarySwitch.on = [theImageAndMediaItem isPrimary];
        postToWebSwitch.on = [[theImageAndMediaItem.mediaManagedObj valueForKey:@"postToWeb"] boolValue];
        descriptionView.text = [theImageAndMediaItem.mediaManagedObj valueForKey:@"desc"];
        updatedBy.text = [theImageAndMediaItem.mediaManagedObj valueForKey:@"updatedBy"];

        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
        [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
        NSString *theFormattedDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:[theImageAndMediaItem.mediaManagedObj valueForKey:@"updateDate"]];
        updateDate.text = theFormattedDate;

        orderNbr.text = [[theImageAndMediaItem.mediaManagedObj valueForKey:@"order"] stringValue];

    }



    -(IBAction)postToWebValueChanged:(id)sender
    {
        UISwitch *theSwitch = sender;
        [theImageAndMediaItem.mediaManagedObj setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:theSwitch.on] forKey:@"postToWeb"];
    }




    -(IBAction)primaryValueChanged:(id)sender
    {
        UISwitch *theSwitch = sender;
        [theImageAndMediaItem.mediaManagedObj setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:theSwitch.on] forKey:@"primary"];

    }
```

...

[image]

```
-(void)handleDoubleTapRecognizer:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
    {
        NSLog(@"Double Tapped on ImageViewerViewController's main image, so opening editor");

        IGCellPath *pathForCurrentCell = [self pathForCurrentCell];
        iRpImageAndMedia *imageAndMediaItem = [thePropertyImageSet objectAtIndex:pathForCurrentCell.columnIndex];

        imageEditorVC = [[iRpImageEditorViewController alloc] initWithImageAndMediaItem:imageAndMediaItem];
        imageEditorVC.navigationItem.title = @"Photo Details Editor";
        imageEditorVC.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(imageEditorDone)];
        imageEditorVC.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;


        [self.navigationController pushViewController:imageEditorVC animated:YES];

    }
```

Comment: what is the self ? Where are you calling this code ?Also why there are multiple instances of same view controller in the navigation stack ?

Comment: I have a double-tap gesture on iRpImageViewerViewController (topmost on the navigation stack), and each time the view is double-tapped, it pushes a image editor view controller onto the stack, that's why there are several of them, none of which appeared.  Each time I double-tap, it's added, but never appears.  self is simply the class that houses this double-tap gesture, and does in fact have a navigationController per the LLDB output.

Comment: can you show how view controller is initialised in initWithImageAndMediaItem ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri  Just added a bunch of code.